# Bot responded two times

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord, nextcord

Ive been working on my bot and tried out cogs but when i tried test running the commands, the bot responded with two response. I looked into my codes and there's only one output (await ctx.send etc) in every command but the bot still responded the command two times. The code editor i am using is Visual Studio Code. Is this a code error that i overlooked or is it VCS's bug?

edit: Ive also tried restarting my pc and host it on heroku. Both end up still with the bot responding twice.

one of the cogs just in case:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from nextcord import client
from nextcord.utils import get

class Moderation(commands.Cog, name="Moderation"):
    def __init__(self, bot:commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases=["Mute"])
    @commands.has_role('Server Council')
    async def mute(self, ctx, member:nextcord.Member):
        role1 = get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
        role2 = get(member.guild.roles, name="Explicit")
        mrole = get(member.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        await member.remove_roles(role1)
        await member.remove_roles(role2)
        await member.add_roles(mrole)
        await ctx.reply(f'{member.mention} has been muted.')

    @commands.command(aliases=["Unmute"])
    @commands.has_role('Server Council')
    async def unmute(self, ctx, member:nextcord.Member):
        role1 = get(member.guild.roles, name="Member")
        mrole = get(member.guild.roles, name="Muted")
        await member.add_roles(role1)
        await member.remove_roles(mrole)
        await ctx.reply(f'{member.mention} has been unmuted.')

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role('Server Council')
    async def lock(self, ctx, channel : nextcord.TextChannel= None):
        if channel is None:
            channel = ctx.message.channel
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages= False)
        await ctx.send("Channel locked down.")

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role('Server Council')
    async def unlock(self, ctx, channel : nextcord.TextChannel= None):
        if channel is None:
            channel = ctx.message.channel
        await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages= None)
        await ctx.send("Channel unlocked.")

def setup(bot: commands.Bot):
    bot.add_cog(Moderation(bot))
```

the response:
https://imgur.com/a/CR3hnv7

Comment: Are you running the bot two times? Shut it down and try again!

Comment: @Dominik nope i didn't. I tried restarting my computer but it still responded twice

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its just my own mistake in a cog `await self.bot.process_commands(message)` sorry for troubling anybody who tried to solve my problem